# Canonical representation of binary decision trees in Ptime?

Tags: computational-complexity, computer-science, decision-trees

I am wondering about the possibility of efficiently (here: in Ptime) representing binary decision trees (BDT) by some other data structure in a way that characterizes their equivalence.

More precisely: a *BDT* is a tree with internal nodes labelled by boolean variables and leaves labelled by 0 or 1. A BDT represents a boolean function in the obvious way. Two BDT A,B are equivalent (A∼B) when they represent the same function (this equivalence is [can be decided in Ptime](http://www.cs.uu.nl/research/techreps/repo/CS-1998/1998-14.pdf)).

A Ptime representation of BDTs is a function $f$ that inputs a BDT and turns it into another data structure/mathematical object, such that:

1. $f$ is computable in Ptime
2. $A\sim B$ if and only if $f(A)=f(B)

Additionally, we may require that we have a way to reconstruct a BDT from a representation:

3. there is a function $g$, also computable in Ptime, such that $g(f(A))\sim A$

The question is

```
Can a Ptime representation of BDT exist?
```

For instance reduced ordered binary decision diagrams (OBDD) validate 2 and 3, but not 1 because with the wrong variable ordering the output might be of exponential size.

I looked up the literature but did not find a complete answer to this question (see below).

---

An element of answer I have: if we moreover assume that the *size* of the objects produced by $f$ and $g$ is linear in the size of the input, we get that $g(f(A))$ produces a constant factor approximation of the smallest BDT equivalent to $A$, which is impossible [unless P=NP](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0022000007000815/1-s2.0-S0022000007000815-main.pdf?_tid=f6079730-2984-11e5-9c56-00000aab0f6c&acdnat=1436808854_228b1e2cb345f2a0299cc38952b74f23).

Can we say anything more general, is it something already known?

---

This question was asked on cstheory.stackexchange:

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/31918/canonical-representation-of-binary-decision-tree-in-ptime

but the answer it got there is not satisfactory: the answer relies on a claim in another post which is not well justified. I asked the author about this but got no satisfactory answer: (answer 3 and comments)

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7563/algorithm-for-optimizing-decision-trees/7963#7963

Comment: Cross-posted from http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/31918 , where it already got a conditional negative answer.

Comment: The answer posted there relies on an other answer with an argumentation gap not addressed by its author.

Comment: Firstly, you should provide a reference to the cstheory.SE version of your question, and describe here why you are not satisfied by the answer you got there; secondly, you might consider adding a top-level- / arXiv tag to increase visibility of this question.

Comment: I edited the question with link on the version in cstheory. But I can't put cs.CC (the arXiv tag for complexity) in the list of MO. Am I doing it wrong?